# Change font name in highlighted empty line Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using rails tinymce (tinymce 5.0), but I'm not able to change the font name in the highlighted empty line. For example, if I have the two lines like shown below:
[image: tinymce with two lines]

Highlight everything and change the font name:
[image: tinymce with highlighted text]

The empty line still in Arial 11 (default font and size):
[image: tinymce with two lines]

Here is my tinymce configuration:

```
 selector: "textarea.tinymce",
  fontsize_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 13pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
  language: "pt_BR",
  toolbar: ["undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic underline subscript superscript",
    "backcolor forecolor removeformat | editimage imageoptions | bullist numlist table |  alignleft alignjustify aligncenter alignright | searchreplace | save "],
  menubar: false,
  plugins: "table, image, imagetools, searchreplace, lists, media, textcolor, autosave, save, paste",
  content_css: ["<%= asset_url 'tinymce-content.css' %>"],
  media_live_embeds: true,
  branding: false,
  width: "767",
  resize: false,
  media_filter_html: false,
  media_live_embeds: true,
  save_enablewhendirty: true,
  paste_retain_style_properties: "font-size,color,font-family",
  paste_webkit_styles: "font-size,color,font-family",
  save_onsavecallback: showPageCount,
  paste_word_valid_elements:"span,p,b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",  
  extended_valid_elements : "video[controlslist|draggable|controls|id|src|data-id|preload|width|height|data-setup],source[src|type]"
```

Is there a way to make the empty line have the selected font name?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE applies fonts by wrapping the selected text within `<span>` elements that contain `style` attributes. The empty line between Test lines does not contain any content to wrap these spans around.

Using your example, the following HTML is generated (obtained using the `code` plugin):

```
<p><span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;">Test line 1</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;">Test line 2</span></p>
```

The empty line is represented by a `<p>` tag. The non-breaking space is a placeholder character to allow TinyMCE to place a cursor there. It is not considered user-generated content, and so the font spans are not applied to it.

Comment: so, is there no way to make the empty lines have a font-family?